# ConstraintLayout inside ConstraintLayout not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've two components `Brand` and `SignInCreateAccount`. Each component created by `ConstraintLayout`. Now, I create `WelcomeScreen` from above components.

Usecase 1: `WelcomeScreen` using still `ConstraintLayout` (`ConstraintLayout` inside `ConstraintLayout`)

```
@Composable
fun WelcomeScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    ConstraintLayout {
        val (brand, formSignIn) = createRefs()

        Brand(modifier = modifier.constrainAs(brand) {
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
        })

        SignInCreateAccount(modifier = modifier.constrainAs(formSignIn) {
            start.linkTo(brand.start)
            end.linkTo(brand.end)
            top.linkTo(brand.bottom)
        })
    }
}
```

Result: Layout preview not show anything

Usecase 2: `WelcomeScreen` using `Column`(`ConstrantLayout` inside `Column`)

```
@Composable
fun WelcomeScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    Column {
        Brand()
        SignInCreateAccount()
    }
}
```

Result: Layout preview show expected result

Brand and SignInCreateAccount components

```
@Composable
fun SignInCreateAccount(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    ConstraintLayout {
        val (titleSignIn, email, buttonContinue, titleOr, buttonSignGuest) = createRefs()

        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.sign_in_create_account),
            modifier = modifier.constrainAs(titleSignIn) {
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
            })

        Text(text = "... Enter your mail", modifier = modifier.constrainAs(email) {
            start.linkTo(titleSignIn.start)
            end.linkTo(titleSignIn.end)
            top.linkTo(titleSignIn.bottom)
        })
    }
}

@Composable
fun Brand(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    ConstraintLayout {
        val (logo, slogan) = createRefs()

        Logo(modifier = modifier.constrainAs(logo) {
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
        })

        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_tagline),
            modifier = modifier.constrainAs(slogan) {
                start.linkTo(logo.start)
                end.linkTo(logo.end)
                top.linkTo(logo.bottom)
            })
    }
}

@Composable
fun Logo(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    lightTheme: Boolean = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight
) {
    val assetId = if (lightTheme) {
        R.drawable.ic_logo_light
    } else {
        R.drawable.ic_logo_dark
    }

    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = assetId),
        modifier = modifier,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

I want to using `ConstraintLayout`(as hobby) as use case 1. But I don't know what I did wrong or is there something wrong with `ConstraintLayout`.

**Update:** I missed a modifier parameter to the inner constraint layouts. However, another problem arose. That layout rearanged correct, but it not show anything: text, image.

[image]

`WelcomeScreen.kt`

```
@Composable
fun WelcomeScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    ConstraintLayout(modifier = modifier) {
        val (brand, formSignIn) = createRefs()

        Brand(modifier = modifier.constrainAs(brand) {
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
        })

        SignInCreateAccount(modifier = modifier.constrainAs(formSignIn) {
            start.linkTo(brand.start)
            end.linkTo(brand.end)
            top.linkTo(brand.bottom)
        })
    }
}

@Composable
fun SignInCreateAccount(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = modifier) {
        val (titleSignIn, email, buttonContinue, titleOr, buttonSignGuest) = createRefs()

        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.sign_in_create_account),
            modifier = modifier.constrainAs(titleSignIn) {
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
            })

        Text(text = "... Enter your mail", modifier = modifier.constrainAs(email) {
            start.linkTo(titleSignIn.start)
            end.linkTo(titleSignIn.end)
            top.linkTo(titleSignIn.bottom)
        })
    }
}

@Composable
fun Brand(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = modifier) {
        val (logo, slogan) = createRefs()

        Logo(modifier = modifier.constrainAs(logo) {
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
        })

        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_tagline),
            modifier = modifier.constrainAs(slogan) {
                start.linkTo(logo.start)
                end.linkTo(logo.end)
                top.linkTo(logo.bottom)
            })
    }
}

@Composable
fun Logo(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    lightTheme: Boolean = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight
) {
    val assetId = if (lightTheme) {
        R.drawable.ic_logo_light
    } else {
        R.drawable.ic_logo_dark
    }

    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = assetId),
        modifier = modifier,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DevPreview() {
    JetsurveyTheme(darkTheme = false) {
        WelcomeScreen()
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to use something complex to build something stupendously simple just because it's a HOBBY? Just try to keep your code as small, simple, and readable as possible.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I really trying  to find a solution to resolved this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing the modifier parameter to the inner constraint layouts (ones in `Brand` and `SignInCreateAccount`), so all the constraints you set on them from the `WelcomeScreen` don't get passed along, and therefore not appearing on the screen.

For example your `Brand` composable should like something like this:

```
@Composable
fun Brand(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = modifier) {
        val (logo, slogan) = createRefs()

        Logo(modifier = modifier.constrainAs(logo) {
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
        })

        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_tagline),
            modifier = modifier.constrainAs(slogan) {
                start.linkTo(logo.start)
                end.linkTo(logo.end)
                top.linkTo(logo.bottom)
            })
    }
}
```

And the `SignInCreateAccount` would look like this

```
@Composable
fun SignInCreateAccount(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = modifier) {
        val (titleSignIn, email, buttonContinue, titleOr, buttonSignGuest) = createRefs()

        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.sign_in_create_account),
            modifier = modifier.constrainAs(titleSignIn) {
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
            })

        Text(text = "... Enter your mail", modifier = modifier.constrainAs(email) {
            start.linkTo(titleSignIn.start)
            end.linkTo(titleSignIn.end)
            top.linkTo(titleSignIn.bottom)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, exactly, I missed a modifier parameter to the inner constraint layouts. Now, layout rearanged correct, but it not show anything: text, image. ![Screen Shot 2021-10-14 at 8 43 13 PM](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30248765/137330051-84a744ee-0837-4665-b26d-b256cba8ca55.png)

Comment: It's look like view set visibility = View.INVISIBLE, [WelcomeScreen.kt](https://gist.github.com/bongtoi/a24db90b4a86a87e2860fb05c3d62e75) at here